in AUR checksum is checksum of what?
In arch linux AUR there is a checksum field. It is easy to calculate checksum of files or archived directories. The thing I cannot find on internet is this AUR checksum is checksum of what?

As usual with Arch Linux, there is a detailed description of PKGBUILDs (scripts used by the makepkg utility to build both the official packages and those from Arch User Repository) on the Arch wiki, and it includes the descriptions of relevant variables:

8.1. cksums
An array CRC32 checksums (from UNIX-standard cksum) of the files listed in the source array.
8.2. md5sums
An array of 128-bit MD5 checksums of the files listed in the source array.
8.3. sha1sums
An array of 160-bit SHA-1 checksums of the files listed in the source array.
8.4. sha256sums
An array of SHA-2 checksums with digest size of 256 bits.
8.5. sha224sums, sha384sums, sha512sums
An array of SHA-2 checksums with digest sizes 224, 384, and 512 bits, respectively. These are less common alternatives to sha256sums.
8.6. b2sums
An array of BLAKE2 checksums with digest size of 512 bits.

The "source" array mentioned here is the array of URLs of program sources (usually tarballs) needed to build the package.

where is this source array? (supposing my project is on github)

It should be a part of a PKGBUILD, as explained in the article.
